# Supplementary in $M_n(\mathbb{K})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to show that the set of $n\times n$ matrices of trace equal to $0$ is supplementary to a subspace of $M_n(\mathbb{K})$.
I wanted to start by determining a set such that the intersection with the above set equals $\{0\}$.
So I need to find a condition in addition to $\operatorname{tr}(A)=0$ which would imply $A$ can only be the null matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the operator $Tr$ is onto $K$, so his kernel's dimension is $n^2 - dim(K) = n^2 -1$.

So a supplementary is necessary a space of dimension $1$. You just have to choose a matrix with a trace non equal to $0$ and the engendred space will be a solution.

The space $\{\lambda I_n\ |\ \lambda \in K\}$ is an example. (And it's also a orthogonal supplementary for usual inner product).

Comment: This is only true if $\operatorname{char}(K)$ does not divide $n$, otherwise $\operatorname{Tr}(\lambda I_n)=n\lambda=0$ in $K$. What will always work is the space $\{\lambda E_11 | \lambda\in K\}$.